# Multiple WooCommerce Single Product Templates

Tags: woocommerce

Following [these instructions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61667/different-template-of-products-for-specific-category-woocommerce) to have WooCommerce load a different 'single-product' template:

```
if( has_term( 'termgoeshere', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $file = 'single-product-newtempforterm.php';
            } else {
                $file = 'single-product.php';
    }

    global $woocommerce;

    load_template( $woocommerce->template_url . $file );
```

I'm experiencing an error:

Warning: require_once(woocommerce/single-product-wide.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/template.php on line 572

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'woocommerce/single-product-wide.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php54/pear') in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/template.php on line 572

I'm not sure where to begin to fix the problem.

Comment: `$woocommerce->template_url` has deprecated since v 2.1 use `wc_get_template_part()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `wc_get_template_part()` instead of `$woocommerce->template_url`.
Keep in mind that you don't need `.php` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a single-product-custom.php template for any product in the "custom" category:

```
 add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_43621049_template_include' );

function so_43621049_template_include( $template ) {
  if ( is_singular('product') && (has_term( 'custom', 'product_cat')) ) {
    $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-custom.php';
  } 
  return $template;
}
```

NB: If you use the same action hooks in your single-product-custom.php template you will get the same look as the default single-product.php. You could 'rename' all the hooks and then could add existing functions (such as those for add to cart buttons, etc) to the new hooks in order to achieve a totally custom look.